# How can I parse JSON objects (like folder format ) shows in Android folder format?

Tags: android, json

My json response should be like this

result: [ { apps: [ { PROD_appsr12: [ { ora: [] }, { logs: [] }, { temp: [] }, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, { pids: [] }, { admin: [] }, { portal: [] }, { appl: [] }, { rgf: [] } ] } ] } ] }

How can I parse above `JSONArray` in dynamically (like folder structure).
this is my code`class Getdata extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Inst_Activity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        if (pref.getString("instraw", null) != null) {
            Log.e("Enter  Not Null>>>", "Not Null");
            spString = pref.getString("instraw", null);
            jsonRes = spString;
            getServerData();
        } else {
            Log.e("Enter Null>>>", "Yes It's Null");
            ServiceHandler handler = new ServiceHandler();
            jsonRes = handler.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            editor.putString("instraw", jsonRes);
            editor.commit();
            getServerData();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(Inst_Activity.this,
                R.layout.schema_item, R.id.textView1, list1));

    }

}

private void getServerData() {

    Log.e("ENTER-getServerData>>>>", "0000000");

    if (jsonRes != null) {

        try {
            mainObj = new JSONObject(jsonRes);

            Iterator<String> keys = mainObj.keys();

            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                Log.e("Main-key>>>>", key);
                methFirst(key);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    } else {

    }

}

private void methFirst(String list2) throws JSONException {

    try {

        Log.e("ENTER-methFirst>>>>", "1111111");

        jsonArray = mainObj.getJSONArray(list2);

        Log.i("MAIN-jsonArray", "" + jsonArray);

        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject Obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            Log.i("MAIN-JSONObject Obj>>>>", "" + Obj);
            getObjMeth(Obj);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}

private void getObjMeth(JSONObject subObj2) {

    Log.e("ENTER-methFirst-1>>>>", "333333333333");

    Log.e("ENTER-getObjMeth>>>>", "entered");

    try {

        Iterator<String> i_keys = subObj2.keys();

        while (i_keys.hasNext()) {
            String strkey = i_keys.next();
            Log.e("getObjMeth-key>>>>", strkey);
            list1.add(strkey);
            Log.e("<<keys-list1>>", "" + list1);
            sub_sub_Obj = new JSONObject();
            sub_sub_Obj = subObj2;

            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(Inst_Activity.this,
                    R.layout.schema_item, R.id.textView1, list1));

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}

private void methFirst1(String list3) {

    Log.e("ENTER-methFirst-1>>>>", "22222222222");

    Log.e("ENTER-methFirst1", "" + list3);

    // Log.e("sub_sub_Obj-methFirst1", "" + sub_sub_Obj);
    list1.clear();
    try {
        // for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        // if (list3 == list1.get(i)) {

        if (list3 == mainObj.keys().toString()) {

            Log.e("<<<matched", "yesssss");

        } else {
            Log.e("waste of time>>>>", "do");
        }
        subArray = sub_sub_Obj.getJSONArray(list3);
        Log.e("size>>>>>>>>>>>", "" + subArray.length());

        for (int j = 0; j < subArray.length(); j++) {

            Log.i("Test----->>>>>>", "test--" + j);

            JSONObject Obj = subArray.getJSONObject(j);
            getObjMeth(Obj);    
            //break;

        }
        // }
        // }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

`
pls help me

Comment: *What you have tried?*

Comment: It's not a valid Json.

Comment: use http://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: please provide valid json response

Comment: mr. Dinithe Pieris this is my response  result: [
{
apps: [
{
PROD_appsr12: [
{
ora: []
},
{
logs: []
},
{
temp: []
},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{
pids: []
},
{
admin: []
},
{
portal: []
},
{
appl: []
},
{
rgf: []
}
]
}
]
}
]
} and i want parse above response in dynamically and showing in android side as folder structure

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the JSONArray you can do it with a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    JSONObject myObject = (JSONObject) myArray.get(i);
    String myString = myObject.getString("myString");
}
```